# Extract Object Values into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tag-it

I am needing to pull all of the names out of the object below and store into an array. 
the reason I am needing this is to be able to use the JQuery tag-it plugin for auto complete.
So if you know of a better way I can do this other than creating a new array I am all ears.

```
    {
  "user": [
    {
      "title": "boss",
      "name": "scott"
    },
    {
      "title": "janitory",
      "name": "bob"
    },
    {
      "title": "dictation",
      "name": "betty"
    },
    {
      "title": "vp",
      "name": "ted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output = ["scott","bob","betty","ted"]

Comment: If you are open to libraries, `underscore` can do this with the `pluck` method.

Comment: Can you show the output (with the appropriate format) that you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = [{name:'Abe'},{name:'Bart'},{name:'Cletus'},{name:'Duffman'}];
var names = arr.map(function(a) { return a.name; });
```

names contains `["Abe", "Bart", "Cletus", "Duffman"]`.

Comment: var names = $.map(quicktestusers.user,function (a) { return a.name; });

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome and IE 10