# Extract all property values into an array in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have an array:

```
var x = [ { id: 1, name: "abc"}, { id: 2, name: "def" }];
```

I want to extract the values of the `id` property into an array, to obtain this:

```
[1, 2]
```

One way to do it, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718199/extract-object-values-into-an-array), is this:

```
var ids = x.map(function(a) { return a.id; });
```

How can one achieve the same result, but using any new feature/syntax in ES6 and in a more concise way?

(I am writing for Node 8)

Comment: Not sure if the code could be composed in a "more concise way". Are you referencing the number of characters used?

Answer (score 2):

Using an arrow function will make it a little more concise:

```
var ids = x.map(a => a.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an arrow function with implicit return to make it slightly more concise:

```
var ids = x.map(a => a.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use **reduce** function of array in ES6

```js
var x = [ { id: 1, name: "abc"}, { id: 2, name: "def" }],
    res = x.reduce((r,v)=>r.concat(v.id),[]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `.reduce()` does not seem as good a fit for this purpose as `.map()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 can I know the reason why reduce is not seems to be good ?

Comment: Because the purpose of `.map()` is to produce a new array that is a 1-to-1 mapping from the original array and that is exactly what this operation wants to do. To produce the summary array in your `.reduce()` version, you have to manually concat a new array for every element which continually makes new arrays, copying all previous values to a new array - all of which is simply not very efficient. Using `.map()` for exactly what it is built for is just more efficient.  You could use `.forEach()` or even a plain `for` loop also.  We're interested in which method is best suited and concise.

Comment: Also, your `.reduce()` method is not more concise than what the OP already has with `var ids = x.map(function(a) { return a.id; });`.